# Как понимать "россыпь рассудка"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Существует ли такое выражение, как *россыпь рассудка*?

Answer (score 2):

Согласно определению рассудка, осмысливая действительность, он 
представляет ее как систему понятий (россыпь звезд). По-моему, "рассудка россыпь" - не рассыпавшийся рассудок, а россыпь звездочек-понятий, созданная рассудком. Красивый образ.

См. [Рассудок](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA)

Comment: В любом случае это -- метафора, и воспринимать смысл ее надо, исходя из контекста ( ну вот, довели, в собственном комментарии запутался)

Answer (score 1):

1. Понимать только как метафору. Очень необычную, почти за гранью умопредставимого.
2. Не существует такого "выражения".

Порассуждаем?

Рассудок - россыпью; что бы это могло быть? Осколки мыслей в помутнённом сознании? "Расколотые сны" Сидни Шелдона?.. О_о

Что-то явно шизоидное; употреблять с осторожностию.

Answer (score 1):

На небе тёмном звёзды — **здравого рассудка россыпь**,
Светили мне на жизненном пути.
Теперь же ночь, **рассудок спит**, лишь мрака поступь,
Едва кометой пролетела ты.

[Ромашкина Ольга. Признание | samlib.ru](http://samlib.ru/r/romashkina_o_w/poezija-34.shtml)

Рассудок, сознание — какие они, как выглядят? Существует, к примеру,  выражение "поток сознания", то есть  непрерывный поток наших мыслей, образов. Но можно представить и другую картину: **сознание — это разбросанные мысли на темном фоне, как звезды на небе.**

Answer (score 0):

**"На меня падало собственное презрение и россыпь мелкого конфетти из рассудка".**

*Рассудок считается обычным состоянием сознания и защитником здравого смысла.*
А что происходит, когда человек обуреваем страстями - любовью, ненавистью, гневом, обидой, жаждой мести?
 Он *перестает* здраво мыслить и адекватно воспринимать реальность, его *цельный рассудок* отключается, рассыпается: перегорает как лампочка или, наоборот, вспыхивает как факел.

месяц я нахожусь в коматозе
гудки в мобильном не прекращаются.
***эрозия разума, россыпь рассудка***
переливается на солнце.
...
будь мной. растворись во мне.
ощути ***блестящую россыпь

рассудка*** в руках.
почувствую весенне-летний ветер.
[Сладкая вата](https://vk.com/topic-19200706_26632593?post=7996)

Думаю, что такая интерпретация вполне возможна.
А выражение действительно необычное, нестандартное.